# sums of series involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, geometric-series

I dont know how to use latex any good rescources to quickly learn from scratch, hence why I have photographed the question.

The question is as follows

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSnr2.png)

[question final part of working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcWgS.png)

The solution is the book to me does not seem very elegant and perhaps long winded so is there a better way to derive the result. For example without changing from the exponential to the modulus argument form.

Maybe use double angle formulae might be better but I am unsure.

Thanks,

Daniel

(PS I dont have enough rep to include the image)

Comment: I don't think its long winded, they just break down each individual step in a lot of detail, making the solution seem quite long. Many of those steps are usually done simultaneously when you actually work through such a problem, which would make it seem nice and short.

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution that is done in the book is good enough,it is not long-winded for me as you are just using the formula for Geometric series and $$\exp(ia)=\cos a+i\sin a$$ and the rest is just basic manipulations.